# put array element value in span jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data = [{"id":"2015-07-003","cname":"John Smith ","caddress":"Tokyo,Japan","ccontact":"123"},{"id":"2015-07-003","cname":"James Harden","caddress":"Osaka Japan","ccontact":"345"}]



$.each(data, function(item, element) {
  alert(element.cname);
  $('#name').text(element.cname);
});


<span id='name'></span>
```

In above i want to put the names in the array inside the span but what is happening is only one name is shown the last one. Meaning the names is overriden how can i iterate the name so all can be shown

I want it to look like

```
John Smith
James Harden
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is using .text() will override the previous value with new one, you need to keep appending the value to the previous one.

So one solution is to create an array of `cname` then use `.join()` to generate the desired output html and use .html() to set the content

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "2015-07-003",
  "cname": "John Smith ",
  "caddress": "Tokyo,Japan",
  "ccontact": "123"
}, {
  "id": "2015-07-003",
  "cname": "James Harden",
  "caddress": "Osaka Japan",
  "ccontact": "345"
}]


$('#name').html($.map(data, function(item) {
  return item.cname
}).join('<br />'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='name'></span>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more flexible i mean i have other span i want to make like this.

Comment: @Pekka there could be if you can explain your requirement - if possible edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/95g4b32k/2/) to recreate your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95g4b32k/3/ then i want to put the value on each span that i added address for span with id address contact for span with id contact

Comment: @Pekka in that case using a `each` loop will be better

Comment: Yes like my code my only problem is how to put multiple values inside one span

Answer (score 3):

use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
  $('#name').append(element.cname+"<br>");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheswaran/a80gr5da/)**

Comment: that wont be multi line though

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '';
$.each(data, function (item, element) {
    str += element.cname + '<br />';
});
$('#name').html(str);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Declare a variable
var data=""

$.each(data, function(item, element) {
//Append element to data variable.

  alert(element.cname);
  data+=element.cname;
});

//Append the entire data to the span at the end.
$('#name').append(data);
```